# MySQL full text search in Backand

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, backend, backand

I'm using Backand as my backend as a service and I'm trying to find a way to add MySQL full-text search in my App.

Can anyone help me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is that you are trying to do? Describe your configuration more pleaae. What is the nature of your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Backand query you can use any MySQL syntax, so just add input parameter (MyText) as the text to be searched on and use this query:

SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    AGAINST ('{{MyText}}' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);